# Problems comparing two arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

In ruby, I am trying to compare a list of URLs with a previous list of URLs, and get only the new ones.

I put the old list in a text file with one URL per line. I am reading the text file into an array like so:

```
oldLines = File.open('logfile.txt', 'r').readlines
```

I have an array of new values populated using the exact same method as the old list, and will probably have some overlap with the old list called 'newLines'. I am trying to get only values that don't match with the old list. Let's say 'newList'.length = 100 and 'oldlist'.length = 95, and I know through visual inspection that something like 90 elements overlap between them.
Things I have tried:

```
newList = newList - oldList
#(newList | oldList) returns 195
#(newList & oldList) returns 0


newList.delete_if { |x| oldList.include?(x) }
```

In both scenarios, nothing gets deleted from newList. I know I am missing something here. Thanks.

Comment: `delete_if` returns a new array, if you catch the return value, you'll probably get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following:

**a.txt**

```
http://yahoo.com
http://google.com
http://bing.com
```

**b.txt**

```
http://bing.com
http://yahoo.com
```

**test.rb**

```
a = File.open('a.txt', 'r').readlines.map!(&:chomp)
b = File.open('b.txt', 'r').readlines.map!(&:chomp)
p a-b #=> ["http://google.com"]
```

Without the `chomp` it fails because in `a.txt` I have `http://yahoo.com\n` while on `b.txt` I simply have `http://yahoo.com` without the `\n` at the end.

Comment: You preempted me. readlines does put the end of line character at the end of the line. It's probably why he's seeing the problems.

Comment: I'm not completely sure `chomp` will suffice, but the thing is the problem lies in the data being different so he needs to check with `p` to see what each entry of `newList` and `oldList` actually looks like and clean it accordingly.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I did a .length on the elements of the different arrays and found there to be a difference. Throwing in the .chomp fixed things nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is invoke the subtract method for arrays, which you did.

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] - ['2', '3', '4']

# => ["1", "5"]
```

Not sure why this isn't working for you. Post some url sample data for your two arrays, problem probably lies there, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn' figure out what's wrong with your code so I got it on irb. And still I don't have any answers. What is newList and oldList. How are these data structures populated? Are they array?

```
irb(main):003:0> oldLines = File.open('/Users/pprakash/old', 'r').readlines
=> ["http://www.google.com\n", "http://yahoo.com\n", "http://slideshare.net\n"]
irb(main):004:0> newLines = File.open('/Users/pprakash/new', 'r').readlines
=> ["http://www.google.com\n", "http://yahoo.com\n", "http://slideshare.net\n", "http://great.com\n", "http://example.com\n"]
irb(main):005:0> x = newLines - oldLines
=> ["http://great.com\n", "http://example.com\n"]
irb(main):006:0> newLines
=> ["http://www.google.com\n", "http://yahoo.com\n", "http://slideshare.net\n", "http://great.com\n", "http://example.com\n"]
irb(main):007:0> oldLines
=> ["http://www.google.com\n", "http://yahoo.com\n", "http://slideshare.net\n"]
irb(main):008:0> newLines = newLines - oldLines
=> ["http://great.com\n", "http://example.com\n"]
irb(main):009:0> newLines
=> ["http://great.com\n", "http://example.com\n"]
irb(main):010:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your problem.  Here is what I did

**urls.txt**

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.digg.com
http://www.slashdot.com
http://www.yahoo.com
```

**urls2.txt**

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.digg.com
http://www.slashdot.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.dzone.com
http://www.digit.com
http://www.digitaldreams.com
```

***Code***

```
first = File.open('urls.txt', 'r').readlines
second = File.open('urls2.txt', 'r').readlines

disjoint = second - first
```

***Update***: Upon attempting a few other things I flubbed my code by chomping the '\n' some of the URLs, and subtracted URLs with '\n' from URLs without '\n' and it didn't remove anything.  So I imagine why you aren't seeing anything removed is some sort of error like that.  Try printing out the two URLs before you subtract them.